# Increment loop In NASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm having trouble trying to get this assembly code to work:

```
section .text
    global _start 
_start: 
loop: 
    mov rax, 4
    mov rdi, 1
    add rsi, 1
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    cmp rsi,11
    jne loop
exit: 
    mov rax,60
    xor rdi,rdi
    syscall
```

The purpose of this code is to increment the value in the *rsi* register and print out its value 10 times. It is written in NASM on a Linux x86_64 machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "print out its value", the linux OS doesn't have "print integer" service, and value `1` is not printable character, and for common linux service `sys_write` you have to provide pointer to the characters, not character itself. Can you show some example of printing the value at least once, in a way like you want it, and then explain what the loop should do? Start probably with some working hello world example, and check it in debugger, how it works? What are the argument values? And you can also use `strace` tool to see what arguments are provided by your code.

Comment: The `rax=4` service is "sys_stat", doesn't make any sense to call this, if you want to "print out" something, as `sys_stat` will gather information about file, it's not printing anything anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple things wrong with your answer, first of all the syscall number. You put the value `4` in rax but for x86_64 linux the value for sys_write is `1`

http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

second, you have an issue with your arguments, the call for sys_write is as follows, `sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char *buf, size_t count)`, where `rdi` is `fd`, `rsi` is `buf`, and `rdx` is `count`. The issue with your call is that you are putting the rsi as the literal value `1` which makes linux go to address `0x1` to look for something to print which obviously is not valid.

consider this example for a valid way to print the number '1' and then a newline

```
section .data
    myNum: db '1', 0xA

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, myNum
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```